# Prove that Composition of Positive Operators is Positive

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that if $S, T$ on finte-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ are positive and commute, then their composition is also positive without utilizing square roots.

First, we will show that $ST$ is self-adjoint. Observe that $(ST)^* = T^* S^* = TS = ST$, where the last equality follows by assumption of commutativity.

Now let $x_1, ..., x_n$ be the orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$ with correspoding eigenvalues $\lambda_1, ...,\lambda_n$, which exists by the Spectral Theorem. Then for any $x\in \mathcal{H}: \langle STx, x\rangle = \langle ST\sum c_ix_i, \sum c_ix_i\rangle = \langle \sum c_i \lambda_i Sx_i, \sum c_i x_i\rangle$. I know that $Sx_i \in E_{\lambda_i}$ and that eigenvectors correspoding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal. So, I am able to cancel some of the terms in the sum. But then what about a term such as $\langle c_i \lambda_i Sx_i, c_j x_j \rangle$, where $x_j$ and $Sx_i$ are in the same eigenspace?
How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commuting self-adjoint linear operators on a finite-dimensional inner product space are simultaneously unitarily diagonalisable. Therefore you may pick an orthonormal basis $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ where each $x_i$ is a **common** eigenvector of $S$ and $T$. The rest is now straightforward.

Comment: Thank you! This indeed helps.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt S$ and $\sqrt T$ also commute. Since $ST=(\sqrt S \sqrt T)^{2}$ and the square of any self-adjoit operator is positive the result follows.

Comment: Hi! I am trying to go without using square roots since we have not covered them yet. Thank you!